# How to create a partial dataframe from another dataframe with a different index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python 3.9, I have declared the following python DataFrame, raw

```py
>>> print(raw)

            Date      AAPL.O   MSFT.O  INTC.O   AMZN.O    GS.N     SPY  \

1     2010-01-04   30.572827   30.950   20.88   133.90  173.08  113.33 

...
```

from which I would like to extract one column (e.g. AAPL.O) and the corresponding `Date` (as index)
I thought that a possible way would be

```py
raw2=pandas.DataFrame(data=raw['AAPL.O'], index=raw['Date'])
```

This doesn't return any error, however, when I print it, I get:

```
Date         AAPL.O   
2010-01-04   NaN
2010-01-05   NaN
...
```

If I remove `index=raw['Date']` from the declaration

```
raw2=pandas.DataFrame(data=raw['AAPL.O'])
```

it works as expected (except for the fact that I don't have the index that I wanted).

So I don't understand why but passing a column of the former dataframe (as data) and another column as index, brings me these unexpected `NaN`.

While there are better ways to achieve my goal, I expected this one to work as well. So probably I am missing something more fundamental which I would like to understand

Answer (score 1):

Well, the index is not part of the data, so it might be part of the  problem.
Even so, I don't really know how it expects to handle the index parameter. It should work with a `df.index`.

Anyway, what you can do

```
raw2=pandas.DataFrame(data=raw[['AAPL.O','Date']])
raw2.set_index('Date')
```

In this case, I have chosen the data from both columns. In fact, I might just do `raw[['AAPL.O','Date']].copy()`.

Comment: Good answer. Also note that if you call `.set_index()` on the first dataframe before subsetting it, then the Date information will automatically be carried over when you select a single column. That's because Pandas automatically includes the index when you select a column from the dataframe.

Comment: Nick, do you mean raw.set_index('Date'), raw2=padas.DataFrame(raw['APPL.O'])?

Comment: eyal0931 I tried, among other options, to include Date in the column selection raw2=pandas.DataFrame(data=raw[['AAPL.O','Date']], index=raw['Date']), however, it didn't work either (guess what? both AAPL.O and Date contained only NaN). Your solution is clear, I was only looking for a compact way to do the same (in just one line, but it doesn't work, passing data and index)